# django models: change the way value of a field gets rendered in admin panel

Tags: django, python-3.x

My model in django has uuid as its primary key:

```
class User(models.Model):
   token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

   def __str__(self):
        return str(self.token).replace('-', '')
```

and since uuid gets saved in the database without dashes(`-`), therefor I could able to render it without dashes using `__str__` in the code above. The result looks like this:

[image]

But how can I do the same thing for the way the value gets rendered in the admin panel (how to remove dashes):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
class User(models.Model):
   token = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)       
   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.token).replace('-', '')

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('render_token',)
    readonly_fields = ('render_token',)

    def render_token(self, obj):
        return str(obj.token).replace('-', '')  # or str(obj)
    render_token.short_description = 'TOKEN'
```

check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: `from django.contrib import admin
from mymodel.models import User

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('token',)

    def token(self, obj):
        return str(obj.token).replace('-', '')  # or str(obj)
    token.short_description = 'token'`

Comment: it is basically exactly the code that you provided. I just changed all `render_token` to `token` because that was my field name.

Comment: no need to rename render_token to token. If you rename, than method render_token will not called. This is done on purpose.

Comment: upon adding a new user in admin panel, this error pops up: **Unknown field(s) (render_token) specified for User.**

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot add that line:         readonly_fields = ('render_token',) (Added in answer)